# Open up iPhone 5s to turn it off

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5s screen is blacked out and I can't turn it off by using the screen and buttons.  How do I open the phone so I can remove the battery to turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

Do not open your iPhone unless you are an experienced with phone repair person . Better take it to an Apple Store or any cellphone repair shop. Otherwise, use iFix guideline. 
https://www.ifixit.com/Device/iPhone_5s

Answer (score 0):

Some faults on iPhones can be solved by manually disconnecting the battery. In order to do this you'll need to remove the LCD screen (which may void your warranty where applicable). If your device is out of warranty and more importantly you have the right tools then there is no harm. First check a video guide (i suggest Jerry Rig on Youtube).
This way you familiarise yourself with the process first.

- The bottom two screws need to be removed with a pentalobe screw driver.
- Once they're out use either a suction cup or a plastic pry tool to lift up the lcd screen. The battery connector is underneath a small metal shield with 3 Phillips screws.
- Once they have also been removed, use your pry tool to remove the battery connector flex cable from the board connector. This will completely (soft) reset the device. After a few seconds reattach the battery connector and power on the iPhone.

Hopefully your device will power up as normal..... othwerise there may be faults which  need further investigation.